# Flutter Unable to read manifest info from app.apk

Tags: android, flutter

i have upgraded the flutter four days earlier and since then i am facing issue, the workspace has no errors as other collaborator's code is running fine.
Error is:

```
Error running com.xxxxxxxx.signals. Default activity not found
Unable to read manifest info from F:\Projects\xxxxxxxx-mobile\xxxxxxxx-mobile\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

i ran following commands in Visual Studio Code Terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

the solutions i applied which unfortunately didnt work are:

1. Then i changed branch of the repository i have working in
2. Switched to dev, beta branches of flutter
3. Re installed emulator
4. attached real device

My flutter doctor is as follows:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.3.13, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.3.13 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 59ce7d6bff (2 days ago), 2019-03-18 11:20:10 -0700
    • Engine revision e75f6de01f
    • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.1.1 None)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\jabir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 32.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5124
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.32.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\jabir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this? I am running into the same problem.

Comment: Nope, but for android i am now using Android Studio 3.3.2 by right click on android module -> Flutter -> Open Android Module In Android Studio then run the app in this windows. let me know if it works or not, i have other solutions too, thanx

Comment: Have you found any easier solution for this one?

Comment: @Steven what error you are stuck in?

Comment: @JabirIshaq same as yours, I recently upgraded some of the sdk tools and created a new AVD (API v10), did some downgrading to API v6 of the AVD but error still persist. I made a post about this on reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/jxltra/problem_with_running_flutter_projects_on_avd/)

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar problem and o fixed it by deleting the app.apk in the build/app/outputs/apk directory and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by these step.

- upgraded flutter
- created new other project using `flutter create foo`
- compared `foo` project with my project

  - removed kotlin setting from my project
  - changed androidx to android.support packages in gradle dependencies
  - copied and modified *.iml files for my project (although these files are ignored)
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter run`

I used VS editor.

My Project dependencies. `pubspec`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.15.7
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.3.4
  firebase_analytics: ^2.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+2
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.1.0+2
  firebase_database: ^2.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  video_player: ^0.10.0+4
  chewie: ^0.9.7
```

Comment: see the answer i posted @Brownsoo Han

Answer (score 1):

in my case it happened cause I defined an intent filter for notification inside main application tag in manifest and declared an application service that receives it in manifest after main application tag and that is wrong
The right to change main application tage name to the new application tag not to put the both

Answer (score 0):

This Error is because the flutter does not find the SDK path. You just need to set the SDK Path by following the command using the terminal.

`flutter config --android-sdk $SDK_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

i solve AndroidManifest.xml could not be found.
Please check D:\Data anonim\Project\project_flutter\flutter_app\app_mobile.android\AndroidManifest.xml for errors. with clean my project snytax

- flutter clean
- flutter create .

Comment: Maybe more details could be helpful :)