# Flutter, Android Manifest issue with flutter run -t method

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I need to set 2 main files for test and dev environment. When I try to run

```
flutter run -t test_app/lib/main.dart
```

I get following errors:

```
AndroidManifest.xml could not be found.
Please check ***/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

And when I use:

```
flutter build apk -t test_app/lib/main.dart
```

I get:

```
[!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new
project.
```

I add the configuration to run this 2 different main files and it works but I need to run this from command line and that's the problem.

I saw similar issues and I tried

- run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

What can cause this issue? Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257232/flutter-unable-to-read-manifest-info-from-app-apk)

Try to fix it by deleting the `app.apk` in the `build/app/outputs/apk`.

Comment: Not working for me :/

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting this Flutter project and create a new Flutter project.